# both are char but i get, invalid conversion from `char' to `char*'

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am writing a program using only C, i am a student and only have 5 months of training. It will open a file, store the lines as strings, count how many strings in the array i used, then close the file. Here is the function i wrote.

```
char animalsarray[100][100], xstring='x';
int numlines1;

void preload(){
  int j; 
  strcpy(animalfile,"animals.txt.");
  animals=fopen(animalfile,"r");
  if(animals==NULL){
    printf("ERROR: animals.txt not found!");
    exit(13);
}
for(j=0;j<100;j++){
    strcpy(xstring, animalsarray[j][0]);
}
j=0;
while(sscanf(animalsarray[j][0],100,animals)!= EOF){
    j++;
}
for(j=0;j==100;j++){
    if(animalsarray[j][0]!='x'){
        numlines1++;
    }
}
fclose(animals);
```

}
The problem i get is this

> error: invalid conversion from `char' to` char*'
>
> error: initializing argument 1 of `char* strcpy(char*, const char*)'
>
> error: invalid conversion from `char' to` const char*'
>
> error: initializing argument 2 of `char* strcpy(char*, const char*)'

Is there something wrong with putting a single char into all the strings?

Comment: Would you be so kind as to tell us on which line the error occurred, and mark that line in your code?

Comment: I speculate it's every place he has `animalsarray[j][0]` or `xstring`

Comment: Have you seen xstring's type? It's not a char* but a simple char.
Also, I quote @KerrekSB. Please, put some more information because we are not mind reader :)

Comment: `strcpy(xstring, animalsarray[j][0]);` -> `animalsarray[j][0]=xstring;`,

Comment: `while(sscanf(animalsarray[j][0],100,animals)!= EOF){` --> `while(fgets(animalsarray[j],100,animals)!= NULL){`

Comment: `for(j=0;j==100;j++){` --> `for(j=0;j<100;j++){`

Comment: possible duplicate of [invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char\*' using strcpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575891/invalid-conversion-from-char-to-char-using-strcpy)

Comment: sorry everone, yes the error is with the arrays and trying to put xstring into the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only are you confusing the order or parametres in `strcpy` (it's destination, then source, so `strcpy(xstring, animalsarray[j][0]);` would have it's parametres inverted), you're confusing a `char` with a `pointer-to-char`.

`xstring` is a char, and you're trying to use it as a string.

If you want to set all the elements of the array to the `'x'` character, try using `memset` instead.

```
for(j=0;j<100;j++){
    memset(&animalsarray[j][0], 100, 'x');
}
```

Although this doesn't set the last character of the array as `'\0'`, so you don't have 0-terminating strings. To have this, add `animalsarray[j][99] = '\0';` just after the `memset(...);`.

If you do want to use `xstring` as a 0-terminated string, it would have to be initialised thusly:

```
*xstring="x";
```